# Lotus Notes on Ubuntu 20.04: install 32 & 64 bit library with different version (libpangox)

Tags: 20.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, libraries, ibm-lotus-notes

I recently upgraded to **Ubuntu 20.04** and I need **Lotus Notes 9.0.1** (32 bits) installed.

After a painfull day installing 32 bit libraries from **Ubuntu 18.04** I managed to get it work.

But I have one conflicting library: **libpangox**

```
# dpkg -i libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 302819 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libpangox-1.0-0:i386 (0.0.2-5) over (0.0.2-5) ...
dpkg: error processing package libpangox-1.0-0:i386 (--install):
 package libpangox-1.0-0:i386 0.0.2-5 cannot be configured because libpangox-1.0-0:amd64 is at a different version (0.0.2-5ubuntu1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpangox-1.0-0:i386
```

But the libpangox 64 bit library is used by AnyDesk:

```
 # apt-rdepends --state-follow=Installed --state-show=Installed -r libpangox-1.0-0:amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpangox-1.0-0:amd64
  Reverse Depends: libgtkglext1 (>= 1.2.0-9)
libgtkglext1
  Reverse Depends: anydesk (6.0.0)
anydesk
```

The version of the two libraries is (almost) the same 0.0.2-5:

```
# dpkg -l | grep libpangox-1.0.0
iF  libpangox-1.0-0:amd64                      0.0.2-5ubuntu1                        amd64        pango library X backend
iU  libpangox-1.0-0:i386                       0.0.2-5                               i386         pango library X backend
```

But 64 bits has ubuntu1 suffix.

In this state, Lotus Notes is not working. I get this error:

> Failed to login

> CLFRJ0005E: Notes is not installed

If I remove AnyDesk (and the related libraries) and reinstall the i386 library:

```
# dpkg -r anydesk
# dpkg -r libgtkglext1:amd64
# dpkg -r libpangox-1.0-0:amd64
# dpkg -i libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5_i386.deb
```

Lotus Notes works again.

Is it possible to get installed the 64 bit (0.0.2-5ubuntu1) and 32 bit (0.0.2-5) libraries with this slight different version?

Regards

Comment: Your amd64 package of `libpangox-1.0-0` contains two changes not included in the i386 version (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/p/pangox-compat/pangox-compat_0.0.2-5ubuntu1/changelog), one of to drop  multiarch, the other is a bug fix. They are not the same thus the different package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, the i386 library has been updated recently. Now I can have AnyDesk and Lotus Notes running.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep libpangox-1.0.0
ii  libpangox-1.0-0:amd64                      0.0.2-5ubuntu1                        amd64        pango library X backend
ii  libpangox-1.0-0:i386                       0.0.2-5ubuntu1                        i386         pango library X backend
```